# wpf listview/gridview column resize event

Tags: wpf, events

I have a listview that is populated from a class object called Props. In the listview I have a field for title and a field for time worked (plus other irrelevant fields). The way I populate the listview is I clear it out and re-add each item from the class object (Props) using foreach. I have a List<> variable that I use as an array of the Props class. I need to update the time worked field for the currently worked object which is always the first object in the listview. I also have a label that I use as an overlay for the time worked. This label is overlayed on the working item (the first item in the listview). It is overlayed on the time worked column. This works perfectly fine except when I resize the column (the first column called title) the label stays in place. I need it to move the label left or right based on the with of the title column.

I know this is unorthodox, but it is the only way I could get the working item to display an updated time worked. Plus, I know this question may be a little confusing, but this is the best way I could explain it.

Thanks,
craig

Comment: You're right that is unorthodox.  Please post your code since a solution depends on how you are going about creating the ListView items and the Label.

Comment: Nevermind, the reason I had to do it this way was because I couldn't figure out how to update the items in the listview. I would do a foreach on the Props items in the listview and update what I needed, but the updates would never show up. This happened until I did Listview.Items.Refresh()